# ANNOYANCE - Pressing F2 Key Creates another instance of Outlook

Tags: outlook

I noticed a while back (not sure how long ago) when I tried to use the F2 key to rename a file in windows explorer, if Outlook was running another instance of it would pop up. This is very annoying since I am trying to write a Python program that uses the function keys. I searched Google and Outlook settings to no avail.

If anyone knows how to deal this I would appreciate an answer.

Thanks
/Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is not normal behaviour for Outlook. I have Outlook open all the time, and use <kbd>F2</kbd> all the time to rename things in several different programs including Explorer.

Check the properties of your shortcut to Outlook, and see if you accidentally set <kbd>F2</kbd> to be the shortcut key.

Comment: Thanks a million. I don't know how that shortcut ever got a shortcut key set to F2. I knew someone around here would be able to answer this question.